# What is the way to copy Array that has nested item in Angular / Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

How can I clone array class object in Angular?

```
ParentModel {
  id: number;

  child1Id: number;
  child2Id: number;

  child1 : ChildModel;
  child2 : ChildModel;
}

ChildModel{
  id: number;
}

parents: ParentModel [] = [];
```

How can I achieve successfully clone parents by full of its children?

Edit: After searching there is no way to do this, We can not do the easiest things with typescript/Angular :)
I created new object and assign each value manually to copy. and also assign child component's attributes manually.

Edit2: const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parents))  first answer in this question works fine too but  I am not sure it has good performance and proper solution.

Comment: `const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parents));`

Comment: can u provide more code (in case the solution provided by cgTag didn't work)

Comment: you can use the spread operator (i.e.  ... (3 dots)) for cloning like  const parent_clone = [...parents];

Comment: @SunnyGoel unfortunately, it does not copy child.

Comment: @cgTag that is the fastest and best way to deep clone anything in javascript as long as you don't have a circular reference inside of one of objects in that array

Answer (score 0):

create another array of the same type and then assign parent array to it so you can easily copy it.

// structure

```
ParentModel {
  id: number;
  child1Id: number;
  child2Id: number;
  child1 : ChildModel;
  child2 : ChildModel;
}
ChildModel{
  id: number;
}
```

component.ts

```
export class ActionComponent implements OnInit
parents: ParentModel [] = [];
parentClone:: ParentModel [] = [];
}    
constructor(){}    
ngOnInit() {
 this.parentClone= this.parents.slice();
}
}
```

this.parents.slice(); this will create new array and assign to this.parentClone with all parent data

Comment: Array.slice() creates shallow copy of the original array. Object references (and not clones) are copied into the new array (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 0):

After a long search

obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))

this is the single method but more efficently

either write your own clone or use deep copy from external library
https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/angular2-import-lodash-into-angular2-application-using-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

Use the spread operator on both parent and childs:

```
const toClone = (p: ParentModel) => ({
 ... p,
 child1: {... p.child1},
 child2: {... p.child2},
});

const clonedParents: ParentsModel[] = parents.map(toClone);
```

(Assuming it's alright to have a shallow clone of `child1` and `child2`)

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this by `deep-copy` an array like this

```
ParentModel {
  id: number;

  child1Id: number;
  child2Id: number;

  child1 : ChildModel;
  child2 : ChildModel;
}

ChildModel{
  id: number;
}

parents: ParentModel [] = [];
child: ChildModel [] = [];
ngOnInit() {
   this.parents.child1 = {...this.child};
   this.parents.child2 = {...this.child};
}
```

Comment: My aim is copying parent with childrens. It does not look proper solution

Comment: `parents` is an Array of `ParentModel`, not a single instance